# Read.Table vs. Read_Table in Readr Package - Extra Columns Added with Readr

Tags: r, readr

I am trying to read a zip file using the `readr` package. My original csv file has 170 columns.

When using the regular `read.table` function to read a zip file into R as such, no extra columns are added:

```
data1 <- read.table(unz(zip_file,csv_file), skip = 10, header=T, quote="\"", sep=",")
```

When I try to reproduce this with `read_table` like below:

```
data2 <- read_table(unz(zip_file,csv_file), skip = 10)
```

there are many more extra columns.

There are 170 columns when I use `read.table` and 1461 with `read_table`.

Below are a list of some the columns from excel (so that you can get an idea of what the original looks like) and I was wondering how I can use the `read_table` function to read everything with no extra columns added:

```
Column Names: 
A
B
C
D (A)
D (B)
E F
G
A B C : 2017 D E - F G: H I
J.org - B : L -- K.org: F C
2016 TEST TESTING : Baltimore TEST TESt: H B
```

There are a bunch of spaces, dashes, colons, etc. that I think are causing the read_table to add the extra columns.

How do I avoid having the extra columns but at the same time keeping the columns in the original format?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `readr::read_table2`? Because `?readr::read_table` says that `read_table` is more strict and that `read_table2` is like `read.table`.

Comment: Also if its a csv file, why not use `readr::read_csv` instead?

Comment: I'm reading a zip file, so in order to unzip the zip file and then the csv, I've read that read.table is a better option

Comment: read_table2 still has a lot more extra columns unfortunately

Comment: @dshkol I completely take that back. read_csv worked perfectly even with unzipping the file. Thanks! Mind putting that down as an answer?

Comment: I did get a bunch of warnings like 4 parsing failures but in the end all the columns are there and it doesn't seem to be an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `readr::read_csv` it should work without adding additional columns as it correctly picks up the appropriate delimiters from your CSV file.

`data2 <- read_csv(unz(zip_file,csv_file), skip = 10)`